# Read from multiple XMLs and write in one XML in Spring batch

Tags: xml, jaxb, spring-batch, jaxb2, spring-oxm

I used **JAXB xjc** tool to generate java classes from my multiple xsd files (I used an online tool to generate xsd files from my xml files).

My problem is that I don't know **how to configure my context.xml to make it read all the classes (and xmls) given AND generate only one final big xml file.**

Here is my context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
<import resource="../config/context.xml" />
<batch:job id="bghJob" parent="simpleJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="xmlItemWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:xml/*.xml" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="xmlItemReader" />
</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="invoiceUnMarshaller" />
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="DocumentType" />
</bean>

<bean id="invoiceUnMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <value>com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.inv.DocumentType</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/Facture.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="invoiceMarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="Facture" />
</bean>

<bean id="invoiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <value>com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.inv.DocumentType</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It seems like I can only **read one class** (for example com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.inv.DocumentType) and I have to specify the root tag but **no one of my generated java classes has the annotation XmlRootElement**

How can I configure my job to achieve my goal please?

Thank you.

Comment: I also have the same requirement... Read the multiple xml files and  write the xml files with some additional data. Could you please tel me how to do this..Can you share the example with me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`contextPath`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html#setContextPath-java.lang.String-) property:

```
<property name="contextPath"
   value="com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.inv:com.yyy.generatedByJaxb.inv"/>
```

This is a list of relevant packages, `:`-separated.

Check also other properties, they might be handy.

Comment: It does not matter how many classes you have. You only have to specify packages which are probably not many.

Comment: Shall I use this property instead of the classesToBeBound one?

Comment: It works (I think) but an error occurs specifying that "Two classes have the same XML type name "XXX". Use at XmlType.name and at XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them."

Comment: Please ask another question, post there your config etc.

Comment: This is a different question, please ask it separately.